# How to share the iPhone screen with a Mac

Tags: ios4

Is there a possibility to share the iPhone screen with a Mac like Steve Jobs did on his iPhone presentation?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile.aspx)

I suppose you can use Skype as well for this, depending on what you want to do and have access to.

Comment: Thank You for quick reply.....Teamviewer is working only to see the desktop on my iphone..But how to see the iphone screen in my mac